# How to do date comparison

Tags: python

How can I compare two dates in python to determine if the second one is after the first one?

Comment: We aren't here to do your homework.

Comment: Like it says - **Use the `date` object from module `datetime` to compare the dates**. Read the documentation for the `datetime` module to find out how to create `date` objects from the strings. Read the documentation some more to find out how to compare the objects.

Comment: It says "use date object from module datetime to compare the date". The homework description tells you exactly what to do. How can you *not* find the way to compare two dates when the homework tells you how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: `datetime.strptime()`

Answer (score 0):

```
def dateAfter(d1, d2):
    from datetime import date
    d1list = d1.split(".")
    day1 = int(d1list[0])
    month1 = int(d1list[1])
    year1 = int(d1list[2])

    d2list = d2.split(".")
    day2 = int(d2list[0])
    month2 = int(d2list[1])
    year2 = int(d2list[2])

    date1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
    date2 = date(year2, month2, day2)

    return date1 > date2

>>> dateAfter("13.12.2010", "08.12.2010")
True
```

Comment: This may be correct code, but how are you helping the OP by doing his homework for him?

Comment: He can consider it a signing bonus. He is sure to come back and ask more questions. He might not even have a good teacher. When you teach, you show your disciple how it is done, first. Then you ask him to repeat what you did, then you correct him here and there, etc. I think the OP has learned alot.